# Does this cross the line to spam?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, spam, self-promotion

While reviewing Low Quality Posts, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25326052).

> [image: answer screenshot]

This kind alerted me so I checked out other answers from this account, which looks [really similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799291/how-can-i-connect-jira-and-vsts/60169843).

> [image]

IMO it is *kind of* weird since the account just got created before the answers were posted.

Anyhow I do understand that these kind of questions are searching for a product or service.

Therefore, is this already spam? Or is it still in the margin of self advertisement, but while still answering the question?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's spam, IMO.

Even if they disclose their affiliation by using the first person they are going a bit overboard with the promotion.

(Note that they use the first person in one of their answers only. In [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60169843/1426539) there is no disclosure, unless you take the *"I will be happy to answer additional questions"* as disclosure.)

I believe the fact that they posted **two answers that exist solely to promote a product** and **have no other content** is a strong enough signal.

Comment: What about the fact that the question asks for a plugin? I think the issue is (like Erik pointed out) that the question should have been closed for asking for an external resource. With that in consideration, though isn't the answer just recommending a plugin? (I do agree that a disclaimer should have been in order).

Comment: @Arnav That's a different issue. I'm not judging if the post is "an answer". I'm judging if the post is "spammy". The posts are only used to promote their product, and they have only posted answers to the effect of promoting the product. That's spam in my book.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that the answerer had posted the same thing _twice_ to two different questions. I think that definitely constitutes spam to me as well.

Comment: So what would be the procedure now? Raising a spam-flag, a custom one explaining that the account _only_ advertises "it self" or just leave a downvote and move on?

Comment: Spam-flag or custom flag. Spam flags have higher priority, I think. And mods investigate these cases anyway, so custom flag to explain the case might be redundant. Although now that it's been posted to meta further flagging may not be necessary. Other users will have either flagged or voted, and one mod or another are usually around taking a loot at meta-things.

Comment: @Twenty Enough red flags (spam/rude) will remove any question or answer automatically. Since we have a community consensus, I'd just raise a red flag

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY0ca.png) is sad.

Comment: Thanks, @yivi, for sharing your sadness. It made me sad, too, so I did something about it.

Answer (score 11):

This is spam. The two keys here are

1. They linked to a paid product they profit from
2. They posted it twice in a row

Even if we allowed link-only answers (which [we don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)), it's a terrible solution to link to your own product, especially when you're only reason to post is shilling said product

Answer (score -2):

The question is the problem, not the answer. That question should have been closed, because it asks for a tool, and we specifically close these questions to avoid answers like the one you linked.

We can hardly blame someone for recommending a tool to a question that asks for a tool. We can, however, blame someone for not disclosing affiliation, but for me it's clear-cut that this user is affiliated with the tool due to the use of *we* and general language.

As curators, we've failed to close this question in time, and we should correct that failure by closing and deleting this question ASAP. In my opinion it's too harsh to punish this person with a spam flag (that has severe consequences for the account), we can, however, add a comment to explain that answers like this are not okay, and when the question gets deleted the answer will be gone too.

Comment: If question *can* attract spam does not make spam post less of a spam. Both should be moderated if you personally consider it spam (the same way you may consider answer to unclear question to actually not providing an answer by downvoting the answer and closing the question).